# Can using line-height < 1 cause problems?

Tags: css

I'm using a specific font (font-size: 16px). When I use `line-height:1`, the character's baseline is not positioned at the bottom. There is a 2px gap:

[image: Screen shot of two lines of text next to each other. On the left the text says "line-height:1 E g" and on the right says "line-height:0.75 E g". The text on the right has a 2px between its gray background and the red top and bottom borders.]

If I reduce the line-height to 0.75 I get better results. I can align the text in a more precise way to other elements. I can implement the spacings defined in graphic mockups without doing extra calculations. Using padding-bottom I can control the line spacing.

Does setting a line-height < 1 have side-effects that I should be aware of? Is it supported by today's browsers in a concise way?

Comment: Even a line-height of `1` is less than the font's height: notice the `g`'s descender is overflowing.

Comment: This question is either too broad, opinion based or requires discussion and so is off-topic for Stack Overflow. If you have a specific, answerable, programming issue, please provide full details.

Comment: In this case 0.75 would divide nicely (16*0.75=12), but generally I would use exact pixel sizes to avoid any `4.56789px` type pixel sizes. Once you go past one decimal place, you can start to cause noticeable inconsistencies in some browsers.

Comment: @user1620220 You are right. But is this itself a problem? I can use margin-bottom to add space. And I can control everything on the basis of base-lines (as graphics designers usually do).

Comment: @DBS If this is the case I could use px to define the line-height.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not call it "bad practice" even though it can cause ugly results when your text wraps over multiple lines. Just using it for "alignment-hacks" like you said should be no problem at all.

**Edit:**

Maybe my Answer promised too much. Be careful with the line-height property beacause as I mentioned it may cause ugly results on multi-line text. If you want to keep your website responsive margins on your paragraphs (positive or negative) are clearly the better solution.

Comment: The responsive-multi-line problem is actually a good argument against this technique. I wonder if the whole issue could be solved on the font design layer, but that's another topic.

Comment: @MrLister Thanks that was my mistake, corrected it to margin

Answer (score -1):

Good practise in this area is the well readable text. Nothing else matters. The text should be easy to read.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but probably this was downvoted because it didn't answer either of the two questions at the bottom of the OP.